# PostgreSQL in PDO never gives error

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I have this code:

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$db = "mydb";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

$dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $user, $pass);

$query = "select * from mytable";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
if ($stmt) {
    echo "Query was OK, execute!";
    $stmt->execute();

    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
} else {
    echo "Query was NOT OK!";

    var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

but it always says

> Query was OK, execute

even if the SQL is blatantly wrong (e.g. `"bogus SQL"` or querying a non-existing table). It always returns a dataset, which is empty when the query is wrong. I know the connection is fine, because a valid query returns valid results.

I do not see any errors anywhere, also not in the logs.

Comment: what do you mean by wrong query>

Comment: @Exprator a query that should generate an error, like `"bogus sql"`, or even querying a non-existing table `"SELECT * FROM this_table_doesnt_exist"`.

Comment: Might be worth trying `if ( $stmt == false )` or `if (!$stmt)`

Comment: try dumping the $stmt for a wrong query and check, the thing happens because $stmt is not blank even for wrong sql, you should rather use num_rows to check if it is greater than 0 in the if statement

Comment: @RiggsFolly makes no difference

Comment: @Exprator I did, `var_dump` shows me: `object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(9) "bogus sql" } `

Comment: now do this if(count($stmt)>0){} and check

Comment: @Exprator `count($stmt)` returns `1`.

Comment: oops sorry take that $stmt->execute outside the if after prepare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> **Note:**
>
> Emulated prepared statements does not communicate with the database server so **PDO::prepare()** does not check the statement.

So you can write whatever to be prepared, only executing it will check it for validity if emulation is on.

You also don't check the return value of `execute()` to see if it succeeded and `fetchAll()` returns an empty array if there are no results by [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Still, wouldn't I have to get an error when I do `$stmt->execute();` ?

Comment: @BartFriedrichs You don't check the return value to see if it failed.

Comment: No, but there is also nothing in the logs. Unless I switch on `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Apparently the default behaviour of PDO is to fail silently.

Comment: @BartFriedrichs Yes, that is the default mode. You have to check for success every step of the way

Comment: Good to know. I'd say that is a design flaw, I like it if my code fails loud and fast ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

> Note:
>
> Emulated prepared statements does not communicate with the database
>   server so PDO::prepare() does not check the statement.

So you can write whatever to be prepared, only executing it will check it for validity if emulation is on.

If you want to try if there is any error, you have to excute it then check if the previous was excuted.

```
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->errorCode() === '00000'){
    // Mean "OK"
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
} else {
    echo "Query was NOT OK!";
    var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Still no cigar. `$dbh->errorInfo()` gives nothing meaningful.